What "hacks" does the Australian rating system (ACF) have to cope with fast improving children?
It seems practically all national rating systems have special rules to advoid issues with deflation due to fast improving children as well as special rules to help these children recorded ratings keep up with their "true rating" as they improve.
How does the Australian rating system do it?

(FIDE does not have such hacks other then higher K for under 18s, but mostly advoids the issues by setting the minimal rating rating well above the standard of most fast improving chess players and only rating players who have played with many fully rated players.)
